# How to read a Excel file in Ada?

Tags: ada

I did a search on google, looking for some lib. to read excel files in Ada, but found nothing ... 
Anyone know any lib. or any way to read these files? 
I just know a method to create the files, but to read, I find nothing ...

Comment: Can you call Java from Ada? Once you do that, Apache POI is well known and I'm sure there are others, and you'll be able to get support.

Comment: @wwkudu That would be difficult, since Java compilers generate Java Virtual Machine code, so you'd have to figure out how to run a program that contains both JVM code and native code (which most Ada compilers generate).  Either that, or find a Java compiler that generates native code or an Ada compiler that generates JVM.

Comment: Sure, but it seems there are some options out there, for example: [AJIS](http://libre.adacore.com/tools/ajis/) & [these University of Las Palmas people](http://www.gedlc.ulpgc.es/docencia/mp_i/Tutor/Ada/s16s4.htm). Not sure how far things have moved on since this [SigAda Conference Paper](http://www.sigada.org/conf/sa98/papers/flint.pdf). Admittedly many of these links are quite old.

Comment: What type of excel file do you want to read?  .xls is quite difficult.  .csv is just comma separated.  .xlsx is basically xml - just get an xml parser.  You can also save excel spreadsheets as .xml, in which case it also requires an xml parser.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a ready to use library to do it, but the parts are available:

Use [Zip-Ada](http://freecode.com/projects/zip-ada) to unpack the `.xlsx` file and [XML/Ada](http://libre.adacore.com/tools/xmlada/) to parse the unpacked contents.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly worth looking at:

http://excel-writer.sf.net

for writing Excel files; I haven't looked at it to see if it also provides read facilities.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but, is just for write excel files!! :(

Answer (score 1):

There is now an Excel **Reader** @ [this site](https://github.com/joakim-strandberg/excel_file_reader).
This for the .xls**x** format, which is actually a .zip containing .xml's, and probably what you are looking for.

Note that the Excel Writer project mentioned above uses an old binary format (BIFF) but provides a tool to read contents (of this same old binary format): biff_dump.